# How to call a Global variable in controller method using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope, controller, global-variables

I have created a global variable in the controller and then I used this variable in a method and after some process, this variable has a value, and now I want to access this variable with this value in another method IS that possible or not please tell me the solution.
And if it is not the right method then please tell me how I can access a variable from one method to another in the controller
My Variable is
`$variable`
and the function is:

```
`public function date_to_db($ui_date){
   $temp = explode('/', $ui_date);
$db_date = $temp[2] . '-' . $temp[1] . '-' . $temp[0];
return $db_date; }`
```

Comment: global variables are rarely a good idea.  If you need to use the value somewhere else you should be injecting (passing) it to the function.  If it's specific to the controller you might consider member variables.  Globals are bad for testing, hard to track and difficult to debug when they go wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$variable = 'test';

function test()
{
    global $variable;

    $value = $variable;

    return $value;  

}
```

or add an index to the global array `$GLOBALS['var'] = 'test';`